# Ajax search shows all results when user empties input?

Tags: php, customization, ajax, jquery

Just managed to get ajax live search working, which means I can get the results instantly when I enter characters in the input. The problem appears when I clear the input, it will show all results. When the page first loads it will not show everything. And I don't want it to show all the results when the user empties the input.

This is the current code:
Input:

```
<input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword" onkeyup="fetch()"></input>
<div id="datafetch">Search results will appear here</div>
```

Ajax fetch JS:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'ajax_fetch' );
function ajax_fetch() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function fetch() {

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
          action: 'data_fetch',
          keyword: jQuery('#keyword').val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
            jQuery('#datafetch').html( data );
        }
    });

}
</script>
<?php
}
```

Ajax fetch PHP:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_data_fetch' , 'data_fetch');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_data_fetch','data_fetch');

function data_fetch() {
    $query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 's' => esc_attr( $_POST['keyword'] ), 'post_type' => 'visitor' ) );
    if( $query->have_posts() ) {
        while( $query->have_posts() ) {
          $query->the_post(); ?>

              <div id="check-in-visitor">
                <a href="mailto:<?php the_author_email(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?><?php the_content(); ?></a>
              </div>
        <?php
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
    else {
        ?>
              <h2 style='font-weight:bold;color:#000'>Nothing Found</h2>
              <div class="alert alert-info">
                <p>Sorry, but nothing matched your search criteria. Please try again with some different keywords.</p>
              </div>
    <?php
    }
  die();
}
```

I understand why it happens, because on user keyup it will show the results, and when nothing is in the input, everything is shown. But I cannot figure out how to solve this.

Comment: What's the code for your `data_fetch` action?

Comment: Updated the first post with the complete code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular WordPress search returns all posts if no search term is entered. You'll notice this when using the default search form. If you don't want your AJAX search to behave this way then you need to check if a search term has been entered before doing anything else:

```
if ( ! empty( $_POST['keyword'] ) && $query->have_posts() ) {
```

Or better yet, just don't send the AJAX request if there's no search term:

```
var keyword = jQuery('#keyword').val();

if ( keyword ) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
          action: 'data_fetch',
          keyword: keyword
        },
        success: function(data) {
            jQuery('#datafetch').html( data );
        }
    });
} else {
    jQuery('#datafetch').html( '' );
}
```

Comment: The javascript you posted works perfectly! Thank you so much for showing me how to do this!

Comment: Do you know maybe why I am getting “You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page” whenever I use the form as a non-logged-in user? If I am logged as admin the form works correctly.